# Comparing Folder Contents in Bash - looking to compare specific digits in the folder names

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I'm trying to compare the contents of one folder against the contents of the other, which I know I can do with

```
diff -rq folder1 folder2
```

but: in folder 1, the contents are all sub-folders named word_12345.1.2, while folder 2 holds files named 12345.1.2.physio. I'm wanting to see which folders in folder1 I have a file for in the second folder. If I have the file for a folder in folder1, the numbers on both the folder in folder1 and the file in folder2 will match.

When I just use `diff -rq folder1 folder2` the output says none of the files match, because the exact names don't match. I'm struggling with where to put the globs to get bash to line up those numerical IDs.

Thanks!

Comment: so `folder1/word_12345.1.2` should match with `folder2/12345.1.2.physio`?

Comment: @LuisMuñoz yep!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Folders with a matching file:"
for folder in folder1/*
do
    if [ -f "folder2/${folder#folder1/word_}.physio" ]
    then
        echo "${folder#folder1/}"
    fi
done
```

which, when executed in the parent directory of both folders, lists those folders in folder1 with a matching file in folder2.

To execute the script, save the code as a textfile, let's say, `matches_with_file.sh`, then do `chmod u+x matches_with_file.sh`, and call it with `./matches_with_file.sh`.